# How to record audio from two audio cards on Raspbeery Pi at the same time

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pyaudio

I have two separate usb audiocards plugged in Raspberry Pi and I want to record input from both of them at the same time. Later on i want to join this two audios to one file.
For now I can't seem to find solution to this at SO.
I'm using PyAudio and I can succesfully open streams for both of those audiocards like this:

```
stream = audio.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE, input=True,input_device_index=index,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
```

Where index stands for index of device which I know already.
PyAudio docs says that to read a stream i need to do something like this:

```
for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    Recordframes.append(data)
```

So my question is how do I manage to read from both streams at the same time?
Any help is appreciated:)

UPD:
I tried this code:

```
import numpy as np
import pyaudio
import wave
import threading
import time
import subprocess

CHUNK = 512
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 5
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "/home/pi/recordedFile1.wav"

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

for i in range(0, p.get_device_count()):
    print(i, p.get_device_info_by_index(i)['name'])


class Recorder:
    def __init__(self):
        self.going = False
        self.process = None

    def record(self, filename):
        try:
            if self.process.is_alive():
                self.going = False
        except AttributeError:
            print("test")
        self.process = threading.Thread(target=self._record)
        self.process.start()
        self.filename = filename

    def _record(self):
        p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        stream = p.open(
            format=FORMAT,
            channels=1,
            rate=RATE,
            input=True,
            frames_per_buffer=CHUNK,
            input_device_index=2)
        stream2 = p.open(
            format=FORMAT,
            channels=1,
            rate=RATE,
            input=True,
            frames_per_buffer=CHUNK,
            input_device_index=3)

        frames = []
        frames2 = []

        self.going = True

        while self.going:
            data = stream.read(CHUNK, exception_on_overflow=False)
            data2 = stream2.read(CHUNK, exception_on_overflow=False)
            frames.append(data)
            frames2.append(data2)

        frames = b''.join(frames);
        frames2 = b''.join(frames2);
        Sdecoded = np.frombuffer(frames, 'int16')
        Mdecoded = np.frombuffer(frames2, 'int16')

        mix = (Sdecoded + Mdecoded)

        signal = np.clip(mix, -32767, 32766)

        encodecoded = wave.struct.pack("%dh" % (len(signal)), *list(signal))

        # print("* done recording")

        stream.stop_stream()
        stream.close()
        stream2.stop_stream()
        stream2.close()
        p.terminate()
        self.going = False

        wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
        wf.setnchannels(1)
        wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
        wf.setframerate(RATE)
        wf.writeframes(encodecoded)
        wf.close()

    def stop_recording(self):
        self.going = False


print('started')
recoder = Recorder()
print('recorded created')
recoder.record("/home/pi/recordedFile1.wav")
print('done recording')
```

But it runs infinitely.

Comment: Have you tried using multiprocessing module?

Comment: @RomanFerenets I didn't because I don't really know how to use it. If you could provide some code to this idea I'd defenitely try it